# Modx: display all pages in one template

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

i'd like to find a way to call `[[*content]]` of every page in one template. I mean something still dynamic so that I could add or remove pages and it would appear in the menu without modifying anything.

http://fr.wix.com/website-template/view/html/tokyo-design

I want to use this kind of navigation with modx. Maybe getresource is the answer but I need to display something like this:

```
<div>[[*contentpage1]]</div>
<div>[[*contentpage2]</div>
<div>[[*contentpage3]]</div>
...
```

Could someone help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are on the right track, using GetResources should be able to do this for you:

"

```
[[!getResources:default=``? &parents=`0` &includeContent=`1` &tpl=`contentoutput`]]
```

"

Then create a new chunk called "contentoutput" which contains the code you want to output, e.g.

"

```
<div>
[[+content]]
</div>
```

"